# How to change the structure of a document in CosmosDB using the SQL API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How do you change the structure of a document or set of documents in CosmosDB when using the SQL API?

For example, how should you go about changing from this:

```
{
    "id": "some-id",
    "StudentId": "some@email.address",1
    // etc.
```

to this:

```
{
    "id": "some-id",
    "StudentEmail": "some@email.address",
    // etc.
```

*It's worth noting that a word often used for the act of changing the structure of items in a database is "migration".  However, in the CosmosDB literature that word seems to be used solely for the act of moving data into a CosmosDB database.*

Comment: Who knew that we will meet here Sean :). Are you using any SDK?

Comment: Hello Gaurav! :)  I'm using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos to connect.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `Cosmos DB SQL API` does not support partial document updates. You would need to [`replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/replace-a-document) the entire document. What you would need to do is fetch the document, make the changes and then replace the item.

You can find the sample code for the same here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/ItemManagement/Program.cs. From the same link, here's the code for replacing a document:

```
private static async Task ReplaceItemAsync(SalesOrder order)
{
    //******************************************************************************************************************
    // 1.5 - Replace a item
    //
    // Just update a property on an existing item and issue a Replace command
    //******************************************************************************************************************
    Console.WriteLine("\n1.5 - Replacing a item using its Id");

    order.ShippedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    ItemResponse<SalesOrder> response = await container.ReplaceItemAsync(
        partitionKey: new PartitionKey(order.AccountNumber),
        id: order.Id,
        item: order);

    SalesOrder updated = response.Resource;
    Console.WriteLine($"Request charge of replace operation: {response.RequestCharge}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Shipped date of updated item: {updated.ShippedDate}");

    order.ShippedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    using (Stream stream = Program.ToStream<SalesOrder>(order))
    {
        using (ResponseMessage responseMessage = await container.ReplaceItemStreamAsync(
            partitionKey: new PartitionKey(order.AccountNumber),
            id: order.Id,
            streamPayload: stream))
        {
            // Item stream operations do not throw exceptions for better performance
            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                SalesOrder streamResponse = FromStream<SalesOrder>(responseMessage.Content);
                Console.WriteLine($"\n1.5.2 - Item replace via stream {streamResponse.Id}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Replace item from stream failed. Status code: {responseMessage.StatusCode} Message: {responseMessage.ErrorMessage}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While replacing, please keep in mind that both `id` and `partition key` value should not change. If any of the values changes, a new document will be created.

Comment: Thanks, @GauravMantri, that makes sense.  Is there a way to do this but processing the document as a JSON document?  Otherwise, we would have to have two POCOs - one for the old version and one for the new.

Comment: Looking at the source code here (https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/ItemManagement/Program.cs#L450), I think you can pass a JSON document. Ultimately you have to get a stream.

Comment: Thanks, that's great!